# Spring Boot Profile as Docker ARGS for Dynamic Run Parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml for a Spring Boot application which has an entry as follows:

```
  paramer:
    image: miko/paramer:0.2.0
    build:
      context: ../paramer-docker/build
      args:
        profile:  docker
    container_name: miko-paramer
    ports:
      - "8050:8050"
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Related Dockerfile is as follows:

```
ARG profile

COPY ./external/paramer-* app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-Dspring.profiles.active=$profile","-jar","app.jar"]
```

However, it throws an error at docker-compose up:

```
miko-paramer | 12:42:54.334 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
miko-paramer | java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'PROFILE' in value "${PROFILE}"
miko-paramer |  at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
miko-paramer |  at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
miko-paramer |  at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:236)
miko-paramer |  at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210)
miko-paramer |  at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveNestedPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:227)
miko-paramer |  at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:83)
miko-paramer |  at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:61)
miko-paramer |  at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.getProperty(AbstractEnvironment.java:530)
miko-paramer |  at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.doGetActiveProfiles(AbstractEnvironment.java:240)
miko-paramer |  at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.getActiveProfiles(AbstractEnvironment.java:226)
miko-paramer |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.configureProfiles(SpringApplication.java:531)
miko-paramer |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.configureEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:454)
miko-paramer |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:335)
miko-paramer |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
miko-paramer |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
miko-paramer |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
miko-paramer |  at com.miko.paramer.ParamerApplication.main(ParamerApplication.java:18)
miko-paramer |  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
miko-paramer |  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
miko-paramer |  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
miko-paramer |  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
miko-paramer |  at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
miko-paramer |  at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
miko-paramer |  at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
miko-paramer |  at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
miko-paramer exited with code 1
```

One can see that `profile` is not replaced and seems as uppercase at logs `PROFILE`

How can I fix it?

Comment: Probably easier just to pass SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE as an env var from the Compose file

Answer (score 0):

From [docker compose-file reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/):

> ARGS
>
> Add build arguments, which are environment variables accessible only during the build process.

As per your use case, I think you need specify `environment` not `args`.

> environment
>
> Add environment variables.

Though you can always have below work-around:

```
ARG buildtime_variable=default_value
ENV env_var_name=$buildtime_variable
```

Source: [Setting Default Docker Environment Variables During Image Build](https://vsupalov.com/docker-build-time-env-values/)